# C++ MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE relative

Tags: c++

i'm trying to move the cursor relative on the screen with this code:

```
input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
ZeroMemory(&input, sizeof(input));
input.mi.mouseData = 0;
input.mi.time = 0;
input.mi.dx = 20;
input.mi.dy = 20;
input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE;
SendInput(1, &input, sizeof(input));
```

The problem is, that the cursor moves like this (current pos | new pos [I get the coords with the "GetCursorPos()" function]):

```
0 0 | 41 41
41 41 | 108 108
108 108 | 174 174
174 174 | 241 241
241 241 | 307 307
307 307 | 374 374
374 374 | 441 441
```

Can someone help me please with this?

Comment: What are those numbers, and where are you getting them from?

Comment: The numbers are the cursor coords, i get them with "GetCursorPos()"

Comment: Thanks. (Although it's better to add useful information like that to the question itself rather than in comments.)

Comment: Yes, sorry i was a bit in hurry. I added it now.

Answer (score 3):

The system may coalesce mouse movements, since you didn't specify `MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE`.

More importantly, you are specifying the raw mouse movement, which can get adjusted by the system, as described in [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646273(v=vs.85).aspx).

> Relative mouse motion is subject to the effects of the mouse speed and
>   the two-mouse threshold values. [...] If the specified distance along
>   either the x or y axis is greater than the first mouse threshold
>   value, and the mouse speed is not zero, the system doubles the
>   distance. If the specified distance along either the x or y axis is
>   greater than the second mouse threshold value, and the mouse speed is
>   equal to two, the system doubles the distance that resulted from
>   applying the first threshold test. It is thus possible for the system
>   to multiply specified relative mouse movement along the x or y axis by
>   up to four times.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i modifyed my code like this: 

`input.mi.dwFlags = (MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE_NOCOALESCE | MOUSEEVENTF_MOVE);`

To the mouse speed:

`int speed = 0;`
`SystemParametersInfo(SPI_SETMOUSESPEED, 0, (LPVOID)speed, SPIF_UPDATEINIFILE || SPIF_SENDCHANGE || SPIF_SENDWININICHANGE);`

The coords did change a little bit, but the are still not correct.
The new coords are like (0|0, 25|25, 65|65, 104|104, ...)

Comment: GetCursorPos() returns virtual screen space coords.  RAWINPUT takes normalized device coords.  Normalized device coords are from 0 - 0xffff, virtual screen coords could be just about anything.  You need to y = mx + b the cursor pos to turn it into normalized device coords.  use GetSystemMetrics(SM_XVIRTUALSCREEN | SM_YVIRTUALSCREEN | SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN | SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN), to find the virtual screen coords.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem recently. I solved it by modified the windows mouse properties in `Control Panel -> Mouse Properties -> Pointer Options -> Enhance pointer precision`, uncheck it. After that, all the win32 API Mouse events just work like a charm.